# Expressjs JavaScript Fundamentals: exports = module.exports = createApplication;

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I don't know what this pattern is called, if I did I would look it up directly.

Mainly, how does this work? (This code is taken from Express.js)

```
exports = module.exports = createApplication;
```

I have seen similar patterns before where there is this type of reference variable chain ex:

```
x = y = z
```

I understand exports vs module.exports but looking at the pattern above it makes me question on how it actually works.

I go by the general rule of thumb that 'module.exports' is the real deal, and 'exports' is its helper, more on this [here](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-exports-vs-module-exports.html)

Is the module pattern like this (without altering module.exports)?

```
exports = module.exports = {};
```

ex:

```
exports.name = 'hello'
```

results to

```
exports = module.exports = {name: 'hello'}
```

What happens when you change the reference on exports?

```
exports = {name: 'bob'}
```

Now when you add to exports, it will reference the `{name: 'bob'} and no longer have any ties with module.exports?

Comment: I recently stepped through a NodeJS application (you might do this your self, try [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) ) and noticed a function that has automagically been wrapped around each module. Its signature was `function(module, exports, /* two other */) { /* the actual module code */ }`. I suspect, `exports` is just a shorthand for `module.exports` as I came across both assignments. So, I don't think theres a difference which left hand side you're using and `exports = module.exports` is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition is correct. I'll work from the bottom up:

### The Node.js Wrapper

Before running any file, Node.js [wraps the entire script](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/885f72105bf0b18007100550f131c85ca56536e0/src/node.js#L796-L797) in an [immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript):

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    // ...script goes here...
});
```

This is how it introduces the `module` and `exports` variables into the scope; they're nothing more special than function arguments.

### Using `exports`

The Node.js docs on `module.exports` and the `exports` alias are pretty helpful. To start out, `module.exports` and the `exports` variable both refer to the same empty object that was created by the module system.

If a module simply needs to export a plain old JavaScript object with some properties set, `exports` is all that's needed:

```
exports.get = function(key) {
    // ...
};

exports.set = function(key, value) {
    // ...
};
```

When code `require()`s this module, the result will look something like:

```
{
    get: [Function],
    set: [Function]
}
```

### Replacing `module.exports`

However, Express exports a constructor function, `createApplication`, as the root value. To export the function itself, rather than just assigning it to a property on the exported object, it must first replace the exported object entirely:

```
module.exports = createApplication;
```

Now, `exports` hasn't been updated and still refers to the old object, whereas `module.exports` is a reference to `createApplication`. But [if you keep reading](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/ccc45a74f89b45a6551bc8ff305581dbc8175bca/lib/express.js#L44-L60), you'll notice that Express exports several other properties in addition to the constructor. While it would be sufficient to assign these to properties on the new value of `module.exports`, it is shorter to reassign `exports` so that it is again an alias to `module.exports`, then assign those properties on `exports`, which is equivalent to assigning them on `module.exports`.

Thus, these examples are functionally equivalent:

```
module.exports = createApplication;

function createApplication() {
    // ...
}

module.exports.application = proto;
module.exports.request = req;
module.exports.response = res;
```

But this one is less verbose:

```
exports = module.exports = createApplication;

function createApplication() {
    // ...
}

exports.application = proto;
exports.request = req;
exports.response = res;
```

Either way, the result is the same, a function named `createApplication` at the root with properties available on it:

```
{
    [Function: createApplication]
    application: [Object],
    request: [Object],
    response: [Object],
    // ...a few other properties...
}
```